# how to center div and span elements along the same line?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I receiving this ugly alignment:
[image]

I wont text spans and div rectangles to be centred vertically to be visually in one line. Here is my html code:

```html
 <div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; width :40px; margin: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px;">label1</span>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width: 50px;">&nbsp;</span>
  
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; width :40px; margin: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px;">label2</span>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width: 50px;">&nbsp;</span>
  
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; width :40px; margin: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px;">label3</span>
 </div>
```

I cannot use the way like "paddind-bottom: 5px;" because I generate this html code programically and font size as well as div width and height changes frequently. So my question is how to align my elements in the way, independent of their sizes?

Comment: add vertical-align:top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `vertical-align: middle` like so:

```css
span,
div {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; width :40px; margin: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px;">label1</span>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width: 50px;">&nbsp;</span>

  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; width :40px; margin: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px;">label2</span>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width: 50px;">&nbsp;</span>

  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; width :40px; margin: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px;">label3</span>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could wrap everything in a flex container and align the items center. Then you would remove `margin: auto` declarations on your html elements like so:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  padding-left: 0.5rem
}
```

```html
<div class='flex'>
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; width :40px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px;">label1</span>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width: 50px;">&nbsp;</span>

  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; width :40px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px;">label2</span>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width: 50px;">&nbsp;</span>

  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; width :40px;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px;">label3</span>
</div>
```

I also added `padding-left` to the span elements so they have a little spacing from the labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vertical-align: top;`  on all those `inline-blocks`, but you should use classes, not inline styles

```css
.alignclass {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="alignclass" style="background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; width :40px; margin: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span class="alignclass" style="font-size: 30px;">label1</span>
  <span class="alignclass" style="width: 50px;">&nbsp;</span>

  <div class="alignclass" style="background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; width :40px; margin: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span class="alignclass" style="font-size: 30px;">label2</span>
  <span class="alignclass" style="width: 50px;">&nbsp;</span>

  <div class="alignclass" style="background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; width :40px; margin: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span class="alignclass" style="font-size: 30px;">label3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Line height can solve your problem,

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; line-height: 35px; width :40px; margin: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px;">label1</span>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width: 50px;">&nbsp;</span>
  
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; line-height: 35px; width :40px; margin: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px;">label2</span>
  <span style="display:inline-block; width: 50px;">&nbsp;</span>
  
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightgrey; height: 25px; line-height: 35px; width :40px; margin: auto;">&nbsp;</div>
  <span style="display:inline-block; font-size: 30px;">label3</span>
 </div>
```